# SQL Server cursor Implementation in BigQuery: Perform Different Operations Based on Fetched Row Values

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery

I am trying to convert a cursor from SQL Server to BigQuery Standard SQL. Can we do it using a while loop? What is the best approach to write below cursor scenario in BigQuery? Thanks in advance!

```
declare @t1 int, @t2 int, @t3 int, @id int
declare @name varchar(30), @status varchar(30)

declare @cursor cursor

set @cursor = cursor for select * from table_A

open @cursor
fetch next from @cursor into @t1, @t2, @t3, @id, @name, @status

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin

delete from table_B where id = @id

update table_B b 
set b.time = gettime() /*this can give different results if I try batch processing*/
where b.name = @name
and b.status = @status

if (@t1 is null and @t2 is null)
begin
insert into table_C (parent, child)
select 0, 0
end

if (@t2 is null and @t3 is null)
begin
insert into table_C (parent, child, level, is_above, is_below) /*this insert is different from above insert*/
select @t1, @t2, 3, 2, 1
end

fetch next from @cursor into @t1, @t2, @t3, @id, @name, @status
end

close @cursor

deallocate @cursor
```

Comment: You don't need loops to do these. You can have batch operations with joins.
Can you please show your the structure of table_A, table_B and table_C? Also, where does fetch_status come from?

Comment: Can you explain your logic in plain english? I mean, what do you want to do step by step

Comment: @rmesteves I want to fetch a record from a table A and based on the column values of that record, delete a record from table B, update a record of table B with the current timestamp, then insert something into table C(there are different insert statements based on A's column values--kind of like case statements). That's my requirement.

Comment: @SabriKaragönen I considered loop because there is this update statement which updates table_B records with the current timestamp. If I do batch statements, I get different results. That's my main concern. I updated my code with a comment to highlight this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sabri noted - you DON't need Cursor / loop here at all

So below [script](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#bigquery-scripting) (BigQuery Standard SQL) resembles your initial logic in its simplistic way just to match your in-loop operations one-to-one

```
DELETE FROM table_B
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table_A)

UPDATE table_B b
SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
FROM table_A a
WHERE b.name = a.name
AND b.status = a.status

INSERT INTO table_C (parent, child)
SELECT 0, 0
FROM table_A
WHERE t1 IS NULL 
AND t2 IS NULL 

INSERT INTO table_C (parent, child, level, is_above, is_below) 
SELECT t1, t2, 3, 2, 1
FROM table_A
WHERE t2 IS NULL 
AND t3 IS NULL
```

Comment: If I have to follow this approach, doesn't the 'current_timestamp()' in update vary from what I would have gotten from the SQL code above? I meant to say as I spend some time going over insert statements after the update for the first record, the second record's timestamp changes quite a bit. But if I do a batch, I am going to lose this feature. Am I not?

Comment: obviously there will be same timestamp - but technically speaking speed of computation even in ms sql cursor should be high enough to not to have discrepancy more than within the second. But most importantly - from any practical prospective - the logic in your original script is super simple and catching EXACT time up to milliseconds makes no much sense and practical use

Comment: I agree with you on the practical use being very little to none in catching milliseconds. :)  But that was my requirement. If I have to do that, is using loop my only option?

Comment: i think if catching individual timestamp is a solid requirement - then the loop is the only option. But you should communicate to whoever gave you this requirement and explain pros and cons! obviously set based processing is most efficient approach from any prospective! and not just performance wise - but most importantly for BigQuery - COST wise

Comment: I will do that. thank you, Mikhail. Also, I am accepting this as the answer as it still covers the question to a large extent.